# log4j log.out file not created

Tags: java, log4j

I want to configure `log4j` for My `Java Application`
My Java Application is deploy on `Tomcat8` that is installed on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`

For this i followed the below URL:

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm
```

Steps of Configuration which i do for that :

```
Extract `log4j-1.2.17.tar.gz` file into `/usr/local/`

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/apache-log4j-1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/apache-log4j-1.2.17/

Manually created log4j.properties file into /usr/local/apache-log4j-1.2.17/

Save log4j.properties file with the below content

# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /home/mobile/log
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

My Java Code :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class log4jExample
{
    public getName()
    {
        String xyz = "asdasd as asd";
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(log4jExample.class.getName());
        System.out.println("INSIDE getName");
        log.debug("DEBUG>>>>>>>>>>>>"+xyz);
        log.info("INFO>>>>>>>>>>>>"+xyz);
    }
}
```

Problem is that, When i deploy this application on Tomcat8 and run this, `catalina.out` show `INSIDE getName` but for `log4j` there is **no file created on** `/home/mobile/log/`

Comment: Make sure your application has write permission to the directory /home/mobile/log/

Comment: @AGdev how can i check this?

Comment: First check which user is running your tomcat.i.e(login id), then check permission using ls -ltr /home/mobile/log

Comment: @AGdev when i run "ls -ltr /home/mobile/log/" it gives me "total 0"

Comment: @AGdev after restart Ubuntu when i execute my application, it Write on Tomcat8 log "INSIDE getName" after it will show "log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (pck.log4jExample).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info."

Comment: @AGdev when i run "echo $PATH" it shows me "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/apache-log4j-1.2.17/" so this should be issue?

Comment: log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.home}/logs/mobile.log. Please try this, your tomcat should have write access.